# How to use regular expressions over multiple lines with Python 3.5?

Tags: python, regex

If i have the following

```
string = '''This is a
    multiline string
    for example purposes
    more stuff'''
```

I want to use regex to find just the two middle lines, how would I do that?

Comment: Do you mean the second and third line, or all lines between the first and last? Can't you just split into lines and get those you need?

Comment: SO isn't here to write code from scratch for you. You should make an attempt at solving your problem first, then come back and ask a specific question if your solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.*` to capture a whole line minus the newline character and `\n` to capture the newline character. For example:

```
import re

string = '''This is a
    multiline string
    for example purposes
    more stuff'''

r = re.search('^.*\n(.*)\n(.*)\n.*$', string)
print r.group(0) # Whole match
print r.group(1) # Second line
print r.group(2) # Third line
```

In this example, however, it makes more sense to split the string into an array of lines.

```
print string.split('\n')[1] # Prints the second line
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally if you want to search for matches of a `regex` over a string that has multiple lines, meaning it includes `\n`, you use the multiline modifier.

`re.compile(r'<YOUR REGEX>', re.MULTILINE)`

https://regex101.com/r/pK4aR8/1